# Can I send batch message to AWS SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I am developing an application in which I need to send multiple events to SNS. Is there any way to send all the events in batch or do I need to send/ publish using a for-loop (I'm using Java) one by one to the SNS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `publish()` API call only sends one message.

You will need to loop through your data and call `publish()` for each message.

Comment: Thanks @John. Is there any way I can validate if the publish is successful. I can see the "PublishResponse" returns only the message id. Can I check the status and validate?

Comment: Please check:  
Amazon SNS Topic Attributes for Message Delivery Status and Viewing Amazon CloudWatch Metrics
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-topic-attributes.html
or
Logs for SMS Deliveries in the Amazon SNS Developer Guide
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_cloudwatch.html

Comment: @RoyalTiger *publish* is when you send the message into SNS.  If you get a MessageId back, then the publish succeeded, otherwise there could be no MessageId.  Or, you might be referring to verifying *delivery* which is the asynchronous hand-off to the subscriber(s) on the other side of the SNS topic.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot You are right. I can always handle this on the receiver side as you said. If an SQS is subscribed to the SNS, I can verify if the SQS got the message.

Answer (score 7):

SNS now supports publishing a batch of messages!

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/11/amazon-sns-supports-publishing-batches-messages-single-api-request/

Answer (score 2):

You can publish a batch of 10 messages in a single request now. It reduces the cost of API requests by 90%.

[Link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/publishing-messages-in-batch-to-amazon-sns-topics/) has the Java code references of bulk publishing.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to publish multiple events, then I suggest to use EventBridge instead of SNS. It might cost a little more but We can pass around 10 events/ API call using EventBridge `PutEvents` API.

You can specify upto 5 targets as Lambda, SQS, etc. It can connect to all the services the SNS can pass on to and more.